# Looking for a generalization of fast Fourier transform form for Gauss sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algorithms, fourier-analysis

I want to compute quickly compute a sum of the form

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N}\sum_{l=0}^{M} e(g^{a^k*b^l})$$

Assume $a^N = b^M = 1$ modulo $q-1$.
Where $e(x) = e^{2\pi ix /q}$. This is very similar to the regular Fourier transform that can be done quickly. Any generalizations that apply to powers?

$g$ is an element modulo $q$. Equivalently, I am trying to find the sum of $g^{a^kb^l}$ faster than $O(NM)$.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on notation? What is $g$?

Comment: $g$ is a number modulo $q$.

Comment: E.g. looking at the polynomial sum $x^{a^k*b^l}$ modulo $q$

Comment: Is $q$ a prime/prime power? If it is you can solve this in $O(q\log q)$

Comment: Yes, $q$ is large prime ~200 bits but $a,b$ are elements of smaller order modulo $q-1$

Comment: @CommandMaster would like something faster than $O(q)$, something like $O(M+N log(M+N))$ would do the trick where $M,N$ are order of $a,b$

Comment: The exponent has modulus $q-1$, I don't see how $a^N \equiv b^M \equiv 1 \pmod q$ is relevant.

Comment: Meant modulo $q-1$.
Basically, I'm trying to evaluate the polynomial $\sum x^{a^k * b^l}$ modulo $q$ where $a,b$ have smallish order in $q-1$.